# Changing the current input port in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I change the input port in racket?

That is, suppose I create a new input port:

```
(define my-port (open-input-string "this is a test"))
```

How can I make it so that `(current-input-port)` returns `my-port` now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(current-input-port my-port)
```

Don't do this at the `racket` REPL! This will cause all subsequent REPL input to come from that source. (It's okay to run inside DrRacket, however, even in the DrRacket REPL.)

Answer (score 8):

To add to Chris' answer; the current input port is what's known as a "parameter", which is very approximately a dynamically scoped setting/variable. In general, it's cleaner and more conservative to set the current input port only temporarily, using 'parameterize'.  Like this:

```
(parameterize ([current-input-port my-port])
  ... do some stuff ...
  )
```

Evaluating this code will cause the input-port to be set for your body code and any code that it calls, but won't "bleed over" into code that's evaluated outside; it will also undo the change on an exceptional or continuation-based exit.

Comment: I looked up parameterize on the racket docs but I'm having trouble understanding it. How does racket know that current-input-port is a function that mutates some hidden value? Or does it just take all side effects and make them temporary (only for within ... do some stuff ... and then it changes them back)?

Comment: A `parameter` is simply a function that can be called with 0 or 1 arguments. Pass it 1 argument and it will "set" a new value. Pass it 0 arguments and it will "get" the current value. Make sense so far?  Next, `parameterize` will work with any such function. It simply does a "get" to save the original value, a "set" of the value you want, then it executes your "..do some some stuff..", and it restores the original values (it does a "set" of the values it originally "get"-ed, or erm, 'got"). Finally it returns the value of your "..do some stuff..".

Comment: p.s. I oversimplified that to answer what I thought was the gist of your question. Actually, a Racket `parameter` is also per-thread. Also, `parameterize` lets you save/set/restore more than one parameter, which is convenient. It's also quite possible there are other nuances that yoda-level Racketeers could point out. But again, I just wanted to answer "How does `parameterize` know that `current-input-port` is a function that mutates a hidden variable?".